# Updating a Cordova plugin to certain version

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Just upgraded to Cordova 3.4.

Trying to update a plugin to a certain version

using the Cordova cli

> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.4.0

`Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.4.0" via plugin registry
Error: Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/registry/registry.js:32:20
    at Request.cb [as _callback] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/registry/registry.js:251:9)
    at self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/request/index.js:257:10)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)`

Is there another way to update a plugin to a certain version?

Comment: It will help if you add more details!!
Especially where are you using the plugin!

Comment: The inappbrowser@0.3 works just want to use 0.4 version. Instead of the 0.5-dev version that installs when using `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Use # rather then @. The way you do this is:

```
cordova plugin add git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git#rOLDERVERSION
```

according to the [Cordova Web Site](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_add_plugin_features)